Securely store token in the browser to use in "two" clients
Context:
I have an .NET Core API that generates JWT and use it to authenticate users, and "two" client applications that use the token to send requests to the API using the token.
My problem is I have one application with two different Stacks (aspx and vue) and I don't want users to login in the ASPX application and then login again to use the VUE pages (it's just one system with two different stacks while I'm migrating, the end result is a VUE application and the ASPX will be deleted), the solution I come up with is to authenticate the user in the aspx login page and immediately store the token as a cookie.
However I'm concerning about security because I can't setup the cookie as SameSite and HttpOnly, because if I do it then VUE won't be able to access the cookie/token to send it as a bearer token to the API, without enabling those configurations my website is vulnerable to XSS attack.
I'm pretty sure this is not a new issue and probably someone already had the same scenario, however I'm not finding any useful tips on how to store the cookie safely in the browser and use it from VUE.

